# solving the log inequality $x\log x\ge \log N$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, logarithms

Let $x$ and $N$ be large positive numbers. Suppose that I know $x\log x\ge \log N$. How to get $x\ge C \frac{\log N}{\log\log N}$?

Comment: If $log(N)>x$, then $xlog(log(N))>xlog(x)>log(N)$

Comment: @TomChalmer Thank you. I have put your answer below as a record.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize Tom Chalmer's answer here:
We want to prove that $x\ge \frac{\log N}{\log\log N}$.
If $x>\log N$, then nothing to be proved. If $x\le\log N$, then $\log N\le x\log x\le x\log\log N$ and we are done.